# jenkins deploy only changed project maven

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, continuous-integration

i have project structure like this

```
 parent pom
      pom.xml
        <module>../siteA</module>
        <module>../siteB</module>
      siteA=>pom.xml
      siteB=>pom.xml
```

A is website and B is website,  but no relation between then just it's in the same repository . and wish one on them connect to API.
what i want is to deploy only A is changed and deploy B is also changed.

thanks

Comment: If there is no relation between modules, why is it a multi-module project?

Comment: A is website and B is website,  but no relation between then just it's in the same repository . and wish one on them connect to API.
what i want is to deploy only A is changed and deploy B is also changed.

Comment: So why are they in a multi-module project?